# App crashing with new layout design

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

As I was designing my program I realized that my layout was not going to work.  So I decide to create a new layout, but when I add the layout to my setcontentview, My application crashes.  When I switch back to the old layout it runs fine. Can someone tell me what I did wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="1280dp"
android:layout_height="800dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_width="1150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_box"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2sp"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="38sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/clear_btn"
    android:onClick="clearbtn"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
/** A1 */
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_A1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivA1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnA1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
/** A2 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_A2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_A1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_A1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivA2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnA2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
/** A3 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_A3"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_A2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_A2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivA3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnA3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
/** A4 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_A4"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_A3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_A3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivA4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/quick_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnA4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
/** B1 */
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/rl_B1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rl_A1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_A1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivB1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnB1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/calculator" />
</RelativeLayout>       
/** B2 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_B2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rl_A2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_A2" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivB2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnB2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
/** B3 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_B3"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rl_A3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_A3">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivB3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/page_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnB3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
/** B4 */
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_B4"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rl_A4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_A4" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivB4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnB4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Did I forget to do something??????????

*Update**

Error Log:

> 12-02 14:32:41.537: D/AndroidRuntime(362): Shutting down VM 12-02
>   14:32:41.537: W/dalvikvm(362): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40014760) 12-02 14:32:41.588:
>   D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 76K, 3% free 6620K/6791K, paused
>   7ms+3ms 12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main 12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{test.tablet.design/test.tablet.design.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-02 14:32:41.588:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
>   12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
>   1> 2-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
>   12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126) 12-02 14:32:41.588:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 12-02 14:32:41.588:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-02 14:32:41.588:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(362): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   test.tablet.design.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 12-02
>   14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
>   12-02 14:32:41.588: E/AndroidRuntime(362):    ... 11 more

Good Layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_width="1150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_box"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2sp"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="38sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/clear_btn"
    android:onClick="clearbtn"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivA1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnA2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivA1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivA1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnA3"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnA2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnA2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnA4"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnA3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnA3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_btn_background" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnB1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivA1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivA1"
    android:background="@drawable/calculator"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnB2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnB1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnA2"
    android:background="@drawable/page_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnB3"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnB2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnA3"
    android:background="@drawable/page_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnB4"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnB3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnA4"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnC1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnB1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnB1"
    android:background="@drawable/page_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnC2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnC1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnB2"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnC3"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnC2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnB3"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_btn_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnC4"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnC3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnB4"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_btn_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the stack trace from the crash ;)

Comment: And maybe the working layout...

Comment: Copy error text from logcat then put it in your question. You'll get better answers.

Comment: Posted Logcat, and good layout

Answer (score 0):

Check MainActivity.java:31
I think you're looking for a view by name, and you're using different IDs in each layout.  Whatever is on the line that gets your NullPointerException will give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks you got me on the right track to find the problem. I forgot to add something. Thanks